# Equivalent in C++ to the pack function in PHP pack('H*', $tagIdAsHex);

Tags: php, c++, arrays, hex

I have this PHP code:

```php
$tagId = 1;    // the original value of tag
$tagIdAsHex = sprintf("%02X", $tagId);    // the tag value in hex format
$tagAsHexBytes = pack('H*', $tagIdAsHex);  // the packed hex value of tag packed into string as a conversion
```

How can I translate that to C++?

```cpp
byte tagId = 1;
auto hexedTag = IntToHex(tagId); //C++ Builder
??
```

Comment: Why do you need to make it a hex string first? `char tagId = 1; char tagAsHexBytes[2]{tagId};` would probably work.

Comment: `$tagAsHexBytes` is only one byte long in your example and that byte has the value `1`.

Comment: @RamezAbiad You are misunderstanding what that spec actually wants. The whole hex+pack thing is needed in PHP because of the way its strings work, but is not actually needed in C++ at all. You can get the same result by simply type-casting an integer to a `char` directly, or just use `int8_t` or `char8_t` instead. The spec wants the Type and Length fields  to be single-byte integers, which is trivial in C++.

Comment: @TedLyngmo  your solutions worked thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code shown is simply converting the integer `1` into a hex-encoded `string` containing `"01"`, and is then parsing that hex `string` into a binary `string` holding a single byte `0x01`.

In C, you can use [`sscanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) in a loop to parse a hex string.

In standard C++, you can use [`std::hex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) and [`std::setw()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) to parse a hex string from any `std::istream`, such as `std::istringstream`, using [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) in a loop.

In C++Builder specifically, you can use its RTL's [`HexToBin()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.HexToBin) function to parse a hex string into a pre-allocated byte array.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<unsigned char> packh(const std::string& s)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> v;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2)
    {
        int n;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << std::hex << s.substr(i, 2);
        ss >> n;
        v.push_back( (unsigned char)n );
    }
    return v;
}
```